# How do I gain access to the files in the /etc/apt folder?

Tags: permissions

I need to do change a filename and copy a file to the folder /etc/apt, but the folder is locked. How do I unlock it?

Comment: What do you mean it's "locked"? Please include in your question: 1) What you are exactly doing (be specific), 2) What the error message is *exactly*, 3) What you are trying to achieve in the first place. Please provide this information by *editing* your question. Oh and be careful changing files there! You can end up in a system without updates for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the sudo command to gain root access. For example:

```
sudo -H /bin/bash
cd /etc/apt
do your editing of files
exit
```

Good practice is to save a copy of the original files (e.g. Adding a .orig suffix), before editing.

Comment: May I suggest `sudo -i` in place of `sudo -H /bin/bash`?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by opening nautilus as root from the terminal:

```
sudo nautilus
```

From there, proceed as you have tried before, change the filename and copy your file

Answer (score 0):

To change a file name:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/somefile /etc/apt/somefile.bak
```

To move a file into that directory:

```
sudo cp ~/somefile2 /etc/apt
```

The ~ supposes that the existing file is in your /home/user directory. If it is somewhere else, for instance Desktop, then:

```
 sudo cp ~/Desktop/somefile2 /etc/apt
```

Please proceed with caution and ask for clarification if needed.